# How to turn PictureBox into a class with "moving functions" and call it from Form.cs?

Tags: c#, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

So I'm trying to make a game were you (the character) move freely on a windows form where the objective is to "eat" smaller characters who move horizontally across the screen. If you intersect with a character larger than you... Game over.

However the problem is that my program is far from effective. I have initialized 5 seperate pictureBoxes as enemies (fish1-fish5) and made if statements for every possible intersect between my character and the enemies. I've tried to make a seperate class for the enemies without any luck. I would love if anyone could help me out with turning a PictureBox as a class with random speed and size features so i can create multiple "enemies" and remove useless if statements.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form

{
    SoundPlayer sndplayr = new SoundPlayer(fishes.Properties.Resources.fishysong);

    private int speed1;
    private int speed2;
    private int speed3;
    private int speed4;
    private int speed5;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    private int y1;
    private int y2;
    private int y3;
    private int y4;
    private int y5;
    private int score;
    private int patrikox;
    private int patrikoy;
    int fish1size;
    int fish2size;
    int fish3size;
    int fish4size;
    int fish5size;
    public Form1()
    {


        sndplayr.PlayLooping();


        patrikox = 1600;
        patrikoy = rnd.Next(0, 900);
        y1 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
        y2 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
        y3 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
        y4 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
        y5 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
        fish1size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
        fish2size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
        fish3size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
        fish4size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
        fish5size = rnd.Next(10, 100);


        InitializeComponent();
        score = 0;



    }
    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        fish1.Height = fish1size;
        fish1.Width = fish1size;
        fish2.Height = fish2size;
        fish2.Width = fish2size;
        fish3.Height = fish3size;
        fish3.Width = fish3size;
        fish4.Height = fish4size;
        fish4.Width = fish4size;
        fish5.Height = fish5size;
        fish5.Width = fish5size;
        speed1 += 2;
        speed2 += 4;
        speed3 += 6;
        speed4 += 8;
        speed5 += 10;
        patrikox -= 10;
        label2.Text = score.ToString();



        fish1.Location = new Point(speed1, y1);
        fish2.Location = new Point(speed2, y2);
        fish3.Location = new Point(speed3, y3);
        fish4.Location = new Point(speed4, y4);
        fish5.Location = new Point(speed5, y5);
        patriko.Location = new Point(patrikox, patrikoy);
        if (fish1.Location.X >= 1600)
        {
            speed1 -= 1600;
            fish1size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            fish1.Height = fish1size;
            fish1.Width = fish1size;
            y1 = rnd.Next(0, 900);  
        }
        else if (fish2.Location.X >= 1600)
        {
            speed2 -= 1600;
            fish2size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            fish2.Height = fish2size;
            fish2.Width = fish2size;
            y2 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
        }
        else if (fish3.Location.X >= 1600)
        {
            speed3 -= 1600;
            fish3size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            fish3.Height = fish3size;
            fish3.Width = fish3size;
            y3 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
        }
        else if (fish4.Location.X >= 1600)
        {
            speed4 -= 1600;
            fish4size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            fish4.Height = fish4size;
            fish4.Width = fish4size;
            y4 = rnd.Next(0, 900);            
        }
        else if (fish5.Location.X >= 1600)
        {
            speed5 -= 1600;
            fish5size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            fish5.Height = fish5size;
            fish5.Width = fish5size;
            y5 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
        }
        else if (patriko.Location.X <= 0)
        {
            patrikox += 1600;
            patrikoy = rnd.Next(0, 900);
        }
        //intersection###########################################################################################
        //intersection###########################################################################################
        if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fish1.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Width >= fish1.Width)
        {
            pictureBox2.Width += 2;
            pictureBox2.Height += 2;
            score += 1;
            speed1 = 0;
            y1 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
            int fish1size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            fish1.Height = fish1size;
            fish1.Width = fish1size;
        }
        else if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fish2.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Width >= fish2.Width)
        {
            pictureBox2.Width += 2;
            pictureBox2.Height += 2;
            score += 1;
            speed2 = 0;
            y2 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
            int fish2size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            fish2.Height = fish2size;
            fish2.Width = fish2size;
        }
        else if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fish3.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Width >= fish3.Width)
        {
            pictureBox2.Width += 2;
            pictureBox2.Height += 2;
            score += 1;
            speed3 = 0;
            y3 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
            int fish3size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            fish3.Height = fish3size;
            fish3.Width = fish3size;
        }
        else if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fish4.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Width >= fish4.Width)
        {
            pictureBox2.Width += 2;
            pictureBox2.Height += 2;
            score += 1;
            speed4 = 0;
            y4 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
            int fish4size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            fish4.Height = fish4size;
            fish4.Width = fish4size;
        }
        else if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fish5.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Width >= fish5.Width)
        {
            pictureBox2.Width += 2;
            pictureBox2.Height += 2;
            score += 1;
            speed5 = 0;
            y5 = rnd.Next(0, 900);
            int fish5size = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            fish5.Height = fish5size;
            fish5.Width = fish5size;
        }


        //game over screen####################################################################################################################
        //game over screen####################################################################################################################
        else if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fish1.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Width <= fish1.Width) Hide();
        else if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fish2.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Width <= fish2.Width) Hide();
        else if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fish3.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Width <= fish3.Width) Hide();
        else if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fish4.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Width <= fish4.Width) Hide();
        else if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fish5.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Width <= fish5.Width) Hide();
        else if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(patriko.Bounds)) Hide();
            Invalidate();

        }

     private void key_Down(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                //Keypressed##########################################################################################################################
                //Keypressed##########################################################################################################################
                int x_player = pictureBox2.Location.X;
                int y_player = pictureBox2.Location.Y;

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y_player += 10;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y_player -= 10;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x_player -= 10;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x_player += 10;
                pictureBox2.Location = new Point(x_player, y_player);


            }
    private void Hide()
    {
        label1.Text = "Game Over";
        fish1.Hide();
        fish2.Hide();
        fish3.Hide();
        fish4.Hide();
        fish5.Hide();
        patriko.Hide();
        pictureBox2.Hide();
    }


}

        }
```

and the enemy class i tried to make:

```
  class enemy : Form
{
    public int fishSpeed { get; set; }
    public int fishSize { get; set; }

    PictureBox fish = new PictureBox
    {
        Name = "lol",
        Size = new Size(fishSize, fishSize),
        Location = new Point(100, 100),
        BackColor = Color.Black

    };
    this.Controls.Add(enemy);
}
```

}

I would love if anyone could help thanks in advance. Sorry if i am not clear enough this is my first time asking on stackoverflow

Comment: The `visual-studio` tag should be used only for questions relating to the Visual Studio IDE, not code you write using it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself